# UpdatePanel with browser caching

Tags: asp.net, header, updatepanel, browser-cache

I recently learned that the `UpdatePanel` uses HTTP requests with the "no-cache" header added. This causes images inside it to be downloaded on every UpdatePanel update. I do not want this.

So how do I prevent this?

I've thought about extending the `UpdatePanel` control and try scraping out the "no-cache"-part of the requests, but surely there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UpdatePanel` will only put the `no-cache` header on its own request for the update, not on requests to other resources like images. Those are handled by the browser like regular requests, even if they're inside the `UpdatePanel` content.
Perhaps you simply forgot to put an `Expires` header on your image?

Comment: I just checked with Fiddler and this indeed seems to be the case!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the contents of the panel manually using jquery. I have done this quite a bit. The pattern I generally use is using a user control, and then capture the text using code like this:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var tw = new TextWriter())
{
       var htmlWriter = new HtmlWriter(tw);

       userControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

       return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This is the result I return to the [PageMethod](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx), I set the html in the specified div, and bang - you're done.

Like so many things in development, you'll eventually hit a wall with the automated tools, and you have to pop down a level in abstraction to make it work. Good luck!

Comment: It's a nice alternative, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think it's the only way you're going to get the finer control you need.